# I did not find the error plese help me, pine script line.new function

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to draw a line from the lowest price to another lowest point but in my code, I have a problem where x1 and y1 are working fine but x2 and y2 are not. the result shows a vertical line on the chart instead of a diagonal line from x1 to x2.

```
// Input for the first low price
var float firstLowPrice = na
firstLowPrice := input.float(title="First Low Price", defval=40.70)

// Input for the second low price
var float secondLowPrice = na
secondLowPrice := input.float(title="Second Low Price", defval=47.63)

// Find the bar index for the first and second low prices
var int firstLowIndex = na
firstLowIndex := ta.barssince(firstLowPrice)
var int secondLowIndex = na
secondLowIndex := ta.barssince(secondLowPrice)

// Initialize variable to store previous line id
var line myLine = na

// Delete previous lines
line.delete(id = myLine)

// Plot line between the two low prices
if not na(firstLowIndex) and not na(secondLowIndex)
    myLine := line.new(x1=firstLowIndex, y1=firstLowPrice, x2=secondLowIndex, y2=secondLowPrice, color=color.blue, width=4)
```

Comment: Please edit your question title to remove the ALL CAPS. "Please help me" and "I couldnt find the error" are not questions. "Why does this code throw an XYZError?" is a question, "why does this code not draw a diagonal line?" is a question, etc

Comment: Pleas edit your question's title so it actually describes the problem you are experiencing... [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)